# How to set scroll position to the level of checked radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

[image]

As you see above, I have a small and narrow `div` and in this div there are `radio buttons`. One of the these radios is always *checked*. **I want to set scroll bar's start position to the level of checked radio button when page loaded.**

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ct346z65/

Comment: please post the code to jsfiddle and provide a link unless it's quite problematic to give you any solution.

Comment: @Skynet fiddle link added

Comment: thanks @hakiko for adding the fiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page loads you can filter through all the radio buttons and find the one that is checked. When you have that button you can just scroll to it with jQuery.

This is the code html:

```
<div id="radioContainer">
    <input type="radio" name="distance" value="1"/>1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="distance" value="2"/>2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="distance" value="3"/>3<br>
    <input type="radio" name="distance" value="4"/>4<br>
    <input type="radio" name="distance" value="5"/>5<br>
    <input checked type="radio" name="distance" value="6"/>7<br>
    <input type="radio" name="distance" value="8"/>8<br>
    <input type="radio" name="distance" value="9"/>10<br>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#radioContainer > input').each(function() {
        var radioInput = $(this);
        if(radioInput.is(':checked')) {
            $('#radioContainer').animate({
                scrollTop: radioInput.offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
});
```

Source for the jQuery scroll to animation: [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ct346z65/4/